# line spacing on entire webpage

Tags: html, css, line, space

I would like to have more space between lines on my webpage. I have tried applying "line-height" in CSS to try and create more space, but I realized it does not work:

https://gyazo.com/63c28f6ce59b8a5e17cf3d9835effa9e

On the picture I have a piece of text inside of a div, p or span. If the text becomes too long it will eventually end up being in several lines. When this happens, I'd like there to be more space between the lines.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just add line `line-height` attribute to your `body` tag? If that doesn't work maybe you use a css framework or third party css files which overwrite it. But without code we can't really help you.

Comment: for questions like these, I'd suggest reproducing the problem/snippet of code on a public service like jsfiddle.net and post it here so we can get a better idea of what you tried and how you can improve/solve it.

Answer (score 2):

That's done precisely with the `line-height` CSS property.

If you want the same `line-height` on your entire website, you can simply apply it on your `body` element like so:

```
body {
  line-height: 1.5; // a numerical value, or
  line-height: 25px; // a pixel value, for example
}
```

You could also target specific tags or classes:

```
// applies to all <p> elements
p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

// applies only to elements with the .my_paragraph class
.my_paragraph {
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

You can read more on the values you can use and the behaviour of `line-height` on [the MDN specification page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following to make sure that line-height applies globally across the whole site:

```
p {
   line-height: 24px;
}
```

or:

```
body,
p {
   line-height: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp is the following example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.small {
    line-height: 70%;
}

p.big {
    line-height: 200%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
The default line height in most browsers is about 110% to 120%.<br>
</p>

<p class="small">
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br>
</p>

<p class="big">
This is a paragraph with a bigger line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a bigger line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a bigger line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a bigger line-height.<br>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use line-height attribute in your body tag just like the example above:

```css
body {
  line-height:2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>This is just a title</h1>
  <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
</body>
```

If this don't work, it can be because of another css file (for example from your css framework if you use one) overwrites the attribute. So try adding the `!important` tag to your `line-height` attribute.